# java-how can someone find out the size of a txt file before creation

Tags: java, string, file

I have an array of strings that I need to save into a txt file.I'm only allowed to make max 64kb files so I need to know when to stop putting strings into the file.
Is there some method that having an array of strings,i can find out how big the file will be without creating the file ?

Comment: Instead of writing to a `FileOutputStream`, write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Stop if it goes over 64kb. If it doesn't, copy it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file going to be ASCII-encoded? If so, every character you write will be 1 byte. Add up the string lengths as you go, and if the total number of characters goes greater than 64k, you know to stop. Don't forget to include newlines between strings, in case you're doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Java brings with it a library to input and output data named NIO. I imagine that you should know about how to use it. If you do not know how to use NIO, look at the following links to learn more:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O

https://blogs.oracle.com/slc/entry/javanio_vs_javaio

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

We all know that all data types are just bytes in the end. With characters, we have the same thing, with a little more detail. The characters (letters, numbers, symbols and so on.) in the World are mapped to a table named Unicode, and using some character encoding algorithms you can get a certain number of bytes when you come to save text to a file. How I'd spend hours talking about it for you, I suggest you take a look at the following links to understand more about character encoding:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049090/character-sets-explained-for-dummies

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding.en

http://unicode-table.com/en/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

By using [Charset](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), [CharsetEncoder](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) and [CharsetDecoder](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html), you can choose a specific character encoding to save your text, depending on, the final size of your file may vary. With the use of UTF-8 (the 8 here means bits), you will end up saving each character in your file with 1 byte each. With UTF-16 (16 here means bits), you will save each character with 2 bytes. This means that as you use a encoding, you end up with a certain number of bytes for each character saved. On the following link you can find the actual encodings supported by the current Java API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

With the NIO library, you do not need to actually save a file to know your size. If you just make the use of [ByteBuffer](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), you may already know the final size of your file without even saving it.

Any questions, please comment.